# Python appending field if key is the same

Tags: python

Hi everyone I have 2 list

```
a = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'total_duration': 0,}, 
{'employee_name': 'B', 'total_duration': 11.0}, 
{'employee_name': 'C', 'total_duration': 9.0}, 
{'employee_name': 'D', 'total_duration':4.0,}, 
{'employee_name': 'E', 'total_duration': 0}]

b = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 28}, 
{'employee_name': 'C', 'actual_duration': 22}, 
{'employee_name': 'D', 'actual_duration': 15}]
```

My desired output is :

```
c = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'total_duration': 0, 'actual_duration': 28}, 
    {'employee_name': 'B', 'total_duration': 11.0 'actual_duration': 0}, 
    {'employee_name': 'C', 'total_duration': 9.0, 'actual_duration': 22}, 
    {'employee_name': 'D', 'total_duration':4.0, 'actual_duration': 15}, 
    {'employee_name': 'E', 'total_duration': 0 'actual_duration': 0}]
```

my question is how can I compare this 2 list and for each employee in list b who is inside list a append the `actual_duration` inside list a and for employee who isn't then append `actual_duration : 0`

I tried

```
if a.employee_name == b.employee_name:
    a.append(b['actual_duration'])
else:
    a.append('actual_duration': 0)
```

but its not working, any help is much appreciated thanks

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sebastian said `is ==` doesn't make sense. You could use an `==` test to do this task, but it would require a double `for` loop: in the inner loop you'd have to search through `b` to find an entry that matches the current dict in the `a` list, and if a matching item isn't found that means you'd be searching through the whole `b` list.

Also, you don't  want to do `a.append` here: that would add a new item to the `a` list, but you actually want to modify the existing items inside `a`.

An efficient way to do this is to first create a new dict to hold the data in `b` so we can look up 'actual_duration' via the 'employee_name' string.

When we loop over the `a` list we use the `.get` method to retrieve the 'actual_duration' from the `temp` dict, so if we can't find a matching entry for that name then we set the 'actual_duration' in `a` to the default value of zero.

```
a = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'total_duration': 0,}, 
{'employee_name': 'B', 'total_duration': 11.0}, 
{'employee_name': 'C', 'total_duration': 9.0}, 
{'employee_name': 'D', 'total_duration':4.0,}, 
{'employee_name': 'E', 'total_duration': 0}]

b = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 28}, 
{'employee_name': 'C', 'actual_duration': 22}, 
{'employee_name': 'D', 'actual_duration': 15}]

temp = {d['employee_name']: d['actual_duration'] for d in b}

for emp in a:
    emp['actual_duration'] = temp.get(emp['employee_name'], 0)

for row in a:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
{'employee_name': 'A', 'total_duration': 0, 'actual_duration': 28}
{'employee_name': 'B', 'total_duration': 11.0, 'actual_duration': 0}
{'employee_name': 'C', 'total_duration': 9.0, 'actual_duration': 22}
{'employee_name': 'D', 'total_duration': 4.0, 'actual_duration': 15}
{'employee_name': 'E', 'total_duration': 0, 'actual_duration': 0}
```

Comment: employee_name 'E' should have a duration of 19 I think.  Not 15.

Comment: @Bill Sorry? In the OP's data employee 'E' has a 'total_duration' of 0, and no 'actual_duration'.

Comment: Sorry I mean employee 'D' should be 19 (4 + 15).

Comment: @Bill The question doesn't say anything about doing arithmetic on those values.

Comment: Yeah I'm not really sure what he/she means by "append the actual_duration inside list a" but I took it to mean add the actual duration to the total duration.  Could be wrong.

Comment: @Bill I suppose the question isn't totally clear, but they do say they want to append `actual_duration : 0` if `b` doesn't have a matching employee_name, so I think it's pretty clear that they want to add a new key, value pair to each dict in `a`.

Answer (score 2):

`is ==` doesn't make sense at all, as both of those are comparisons. Also, since a is a list, it won't have an attribute named `employee_name`. You must want a for loop to iterate over the employees in list `a`, modifying their values for `total_duration` to be whatever it is in list `b`, or 0 if not in list `b`. I'd say it would be better to create a new list, `c`, to avoid modifying `a` while iterating over it:

```
c = []
for index, a_dict in enumerate(a):  
    b_equivalent = next((b_dict['actual_duration'] for b_dict in b if b_dict['employee_name'] == a_dict['employee_name']), 0)
    c.append({'employee_name': a_dict['employee_name'], 'actual_duration': b_equivalent})
```

Note that you are using dictionaries in entirely the wrong way. What you should have is a `employee name:duration` mapping, so a would be just a dictionary instead of a list of dictionaries:

```
>>> employee_durations = {a_dict['employee_name']:a_dict['total_duration'] for a_dict in a}
>>> employee_durations
{'A': 0, 'B': 11.0, 'C': 9.0, 'D': 4.0, 'E': 0}
```

If we did this to both lists, our code would be quite a bit faster and quite a bit less ugly:

```
total_durations = {a_dict['employee_name']:a_dict['total_duration'] for a_dict in a}
actual_durations = {b_dict['employee_name']:b_dict['actual_duration'] for b_dict in b}
adjusted_durations = {}
for name in total_durations:
    adjusted_durations.update({name: actual_durations.get(name, 0)})
```

In fact, this can be boiled down into a one-liner:

```
adjusted_durations = {name:actual_durations.get(name, 0) for name in total_durations}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @PM 2Ring has the right idea - convert the data to dictionaries.  Then summing the durations is easy.

Here's how I would do it:

```
total_durations = {i['employee_name']: i['total_duration'] for i in a}
actual_durations = {i['employee_name']: i['actual_duration'] for i in b}

for emp, duration in actual_durations.items():
    total_durations[emp] = total_durations.get(emp, 0) + duration

print(total_durations)
```

output:

```
{'A': 28, 'B': 11.0, 'C': 31.0, 'D': 19.0, 'E': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'total_duration': 0,}, 
 {'employee_name': 'B', 'total_duration': 11.0}, 
 {'employee_name': 'C', 'total_duration': 9.0}, 
 {'employee_name': 'D', 'total_duration':4.0,}, 
 {'employee_name': 'E', 'total_duration': 0}]

b = [{'employee_name': 'A', 'actual_duration': 28}, 
 {'employee_name': 'C', 'actual_duration': 22}, 
 {'employee_name': 'D', 'actual_duration': 15}]
final_a = [{'employee_name':i['employee_name'], 'total_duration':i['total_duration'], 'actual_duration':0 if not any(i['employee_name'] == c['employee_name'] for c in b) else [c['actual_duration'] for c in b if c['employee_name'] == i['employee_name']][0]} for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[{'actual_duration': 28, 'total_duration': 0, 'employee_name': 'A'}, {'actual_duration': 0, 'total_duration': 11.0, 'employee_name': 'B'}, {'actual_duration': 22, 'total_duration': 9.0, 'employee_name': 'C'}, {'actual_duration': 15, 'total_duration': 4.0, 'employee_name': 'D'}, {'actual_duration': 0, 'total_duration': 0, 'employee_name': 'E'}]
```